Truth table with 3 variables: assesing tautological equivalency
I am trying to answer the following question: "are the propositions ¬p → (q → r) and q → (p ∨ r) tautologically equivalent?"
At first I went down the path of a 4 row only table, for all the posible p and q combinations (out of habit) and then wrote down a column for r based on all its possible combinations with q. I practiced the same method twice (for each proposition) and it let to the same results (TTFT). But then I thought that maybe a 8 row table is the correct way.I practiced it as such and it also led to the same results (TTTTTFTT),so either way, the propositions are indeed tautologically equivalent. But I am wondering, which way is the corrent one?

A truth-table for a formula with $n$ variables has $2^n$ rows. Thus, for 3 propositions we need 8 rows.

This is easier if you convert your implications to disjunctions.
